# SQL Query Time Complexity

Tags: mysql, sql, database, time-complexity

What is the time complexity of simple SQL statements like the following?

```
INSERT into table (col1, col2, col3) values ("a", "b", "c")
```

How does it depend on the following:

1. size of the table
2. datatype of col1, col2
3. number of columns in the table viz. col1, col2, col3, etc

Does this depend on whether I am using MyISAM or InnoDB?

Comment: one more thing, don't use double quotes `"` around the values but instead use single quote `'`

Comment: + 6. InnoDB: INSERTs/transaction: i/t=1: slow because of many commits i/t=very high: problematic because of huge transation log file

Comment: + 8. storage of blob-like types: http://www.mysqlperformanceblog.com/2010/02/09/blob-storage-in-innodb/

Comment: +9 table is not a valid name for a table. The statement will fail very fast.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The MySQL 5.0 documentation has a nice page on this [topic](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/insert-speed.html).

The article provides approximate proportial costs for each of the subtasks involved in an insertion task.

> The time required for inserting a row is determined by the following factors, where the numbers indicate approximate proportions:
>
> Connecting: (3)
>
> Sending query to server: (2)
>
> Parsing query: (2)
>
> Inserting row: (1 × size of row)
>
> Inserting indexes: (1 × number of indexes)
>
> Closing: (1)
>
> This does not take into consideration the initial overhead to open
>   tables, which is done once for each concurrently running query.
>
> The size of the table slows down the insertion of indexes by log N,
>   assuming B-tree indexes.

The rest of article provides techniques for speeding up insertions, useful if insert speed becomes a bottleneck in your application.

Comment: I added the relevant excerpt in case the link rots.

Comment: Link rotted, new link from version 8.0: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/insert-optimization.html

Comment: Don't mind my naive argument, I'm only a beginner in dmbs course and after studying data structures and algorithms course for sophomore year I'm curious why would anyone design a database with log(n) time complexity, why couldn't we use hashtables instead of trees which will pretty much ensure O(1) operations.

Comment: @PawanNirpal the objective is to optimize for faster data retrieval and not index creation.  It's a trade-off to have slow index creating but fast data retrieval.